# Customising Object Explorer

Tags: ssms

Object Explorer shows this:
[image]

But I only want to see Keys and Columns folder expanded when I clicked on database plus icon.
Like this:
[image: I edited the screenshot]

Is there any way to do this via script or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to accomplish it. But it is possible to achieve it by writing an add-in.

If you want - you can try to write your own one. Here is a sample "hello world" add-in  for SSMS2012, that I have written: http://www.ssmsboost.com/create-own-ssms-2012-add-in-sample-code-with-download
If you do not have time for that, you can submit a feature request at the project's website.